# Setting TeX Live path for root

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, latex

I have installed [TeX Live 2011 vanilla](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) and I have trouble setting the TeX Live path for root (in Ubuntu 11.10).

The problem is that when I run `sudo tlmgr` I get:

```
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

To fix the path for non-root it was sufficient to add

```
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
```

to `/etc/profile`.

I have tried adding this same line to `/root/.bashrc` and I have also tried to add it to `/etc/profile.d/zzz-texlive.sh` like Herbert suggest in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26624/tlmgr-inaccessible/26626#26626  but it does not help.

Comment: Indeed this question is unrelated to TeX, but [answered on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257616/sudo-changes-path-why).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Quick fix: since you already have the correct `$PATH` set in your
environment (via the `/etc/profile` modifications) you can use:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr
```

Basically, [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudo) resets the value of
`$PATH` (the whole environment, indeed) to a "known good" one, and is
thus ignoring any changes you made to your local environment.  The
[env](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/env) command above sets the `PATH` variable
in the environment of the `tlmgr` it executes, so it runs with the
value of `$PATH` you specify on the command line.

To avoid typing all that for each TeXlive command, you can define an
[alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) in your shell: add the following line to the `.bashrc` file in
your home:

```
alias psudo='sudo env PATH="$PATH"'
```

and then you can simply issue this at a command prompt:

```
psudo tlmgr
```

In addition, [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudo) does not run a
login shell to execute the command, which is why your "profile.d"
tricks did not work for root.  You can force
[sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/sudo) to execute a command in a
shell, which is an alternate way of achieving the same effect:

```
sudo sh -l -c tlmgr
```

Again you can define a [shell command alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) to shorten this:

```
alias shsudo='sudo sh -l -c'
```

which can be used as:

```
shsudo tlmgr
```

Comment: Do you mind including a full description of how to set `$PATH` in my environment? Also, so I have to do `env` for every command in the TeX Live path that I want to enable for `sudo`? There's quite a lot of binaries in /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux that you might want to run as root.

Comment: @N.N. I've updated the answer with more details; hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Cheers! Appreciate your explanations.

Comment: This is a dramatically more complicated way of doing what was shown in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/66498/setting-tex-live-path-for-root/137836#137836

Answer (score 9):

If you add the symlinks then you won't need to make a script. You can do this two ways:

Using the GUI:

1. `sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr --gui`.
2. Click 'Actions -> Handle symlinks in system dirs'.
3. Click 'Update symbolic links'.

Using the command line (untested, since I used the GUI):

1. `sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr path add`. (find more information at [tlmgr documentation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#path____w32mode_user_admin___add_remove_))

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me: I started `tlmgr` in gui mode with

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr --gui
```

and then in the third menu chose the last item but one (in my German menu, that is menu "Aktionen" (actions?) and item "Verwaltung der symbolischen Links" (administration of symbolic links?). In the ensuing dialogue window I clicked the button "Symbolische Links erneuern" (renew symbolic links?). Now

```
sudo tlmgr --OPTIONS
```

works without problems. I'm sure there's also a command line way of doing this ;)

Comment: This also worked for me!
For non-German speakers, you have to do `Actions>Handle symlinks in system dirs>Update symbolic links`. I had previously appended `:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux` to `secure_path` as a workaround, so I restored `secure_path` to default and logged out and back in again, and I can confirm that it still works. After updating symbolic links via `tlmgr --gui`, `sudo tlmgr --version` and `tlmgr --version`  both yield the same result and everything works as expected. Dankeschön!

Answer (score 1):

To pass the user's `$PATH` to `sudo` I modified `/etc/sudoers` file using the `visudo` command and add the following line:

```
Defaults        exempt_group=<group that I belong to>
```

Now I can execute (e.g.)

```
sudo tlmgr update all
```

or

```
sudo texhash
```

and everything works perfect.

I would greatly appreciate any comments on this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't have to add the directory of `tlmgr` to the path. A simple quick solution is using `which`, e.g.:

```
sudo $(which tlmgr) update --list
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to install and manage TeX Live using "root" privileges.  Instead, create the `/usr/local/texlive` directory, e.g, using sudo, and then change the ownership to the user that will be managing TeX Live.  After that, TeX Live can be installed and updated without using "root" privileges.

Comment: The installation instructions for TexLive do indeed explicitly say that. However everything under `/usr/local` is normally owned by `root`. Is it safe to permanently change it? Actually they are indeed owned by `root`, but readable and executable by everyone, so why doesn't `tlmgr` just work without `sudo` (it didn't the last time I tried, but it was several years ago)?

Comment: Many programs can be installed with simple file copy operations.  The tlmgr program uses many other programs to generate formats, ls-R files, font maps, luatex font caches, etc.  It also works on many platforms, not just linux.  There are examples of system to manage complex systems that have a "systemx" user.  The installer and management tools are run as "root", but drop privileges

Answer (score 1):

I created my account just to tell how it worked for me. I'm not a linux expert but after reviewing A LOT of forums with same issue and related issues  I found this solution, I hope to help. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 right now. For me it's incredible that there is no simpler installation option in both cases texlive and tlmgr:

Steps:

- I Downloaded ISO image of texlive (you have to install perl before
- Mount the image and then open a terminal in the mounted directory:

  ```
  `sudo perl install-tl`
  ```
- I choosed full instalation.
- post instalation PATH export:

`export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; export INFOPATH`

`export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH`

`export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`

- Then I had the same issue, I mean: when I ran `sudo tlmgr: command not found`.

Solution:

- By giving entire PATH to sudo tlmgr in order to Update it:

  sudo /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self
- Then start graphic user interface in order to update all packages and "handle symlinks in system dirs" in Action buton.

  sudo /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr --gui

Answer (score 0):

As shown in https://askubuntu.com/a/137836/596089, you need to run `sudo tlmgr --gui` and do `Actions>Handle symlinks in system dirs>Update symbolic links`. If the superuser can't find tlmgr, you can either temporarily edit the tlmgr dir into `secure_path` via `sudo visudo` or, preferably, `sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr --gui`. This will make sure `sudo tlmgr` and `tlmgr` point to the same version of tlmgr.